# convert a column to datetime but error is encountered

Tags: python, class, error-handling, type-conversion, typeerror

I am trying to convert my column 'period' to the datetime format but I keep getting an error.

my code is:

```
data_aggr_period_prodgroup['period'] = pd.to_datetime(data_aggr_period_prodgroup['period'])
```

However I get a type error that says 'TypeError: <class 'builtin_function_or_method'> is not convertible to datetime'.

How can I fix this?

the column is in this format:
|period|
|:-----|
|11/01/2021|
|10/01/2021|
|09/01/2021|

Comment: please provide a few samples of the column `period` to reproduce the problem and get the fix. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.